# Can't add actor to stage

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I have main class (it's only small part of this class):

```
        ScreenViewport viewport = new ScreenViewport();
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    MyActor actor = new MyActor();
    stage.addActor(actor);
```

and MyActro class:

```
package com.mygdx.game;
```

import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class MyActor extends Actor
{

```
private Actor actor;

public MyActor(Actor actor)
{
    this.actor = actor;
}


public Actor getActor()
{
    return actor;
}
```

}

Eclipse suggests to I should remove argument from constructor. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to new the Actor class to pass into the constructor.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Actor actor = new Actor();
        MyActor myActor = new MyActor(actor);
        stage.AddActor(actor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly trying to create a MyActor with no Actor passed in:

```
MyActor actor = new MyActor();
```

Whereas you only have a constructor for MyActor that takes an Actor:

```
public MyActor(Actor actor)
```

When you say that MyActor extends Actor, do you actually mean it inherits from it? If that's the case, perhaps you shouldn't be trying to encapsulate an Actor within a MyActor. Maybe that is what you want to do, but just give it a bit of a think.

Answer (score 0):

I finally can draw textures on stage.
Is there a way to draw texture on stage but using different way than I using usually: [Link](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx)

Before I started using stage in LibGdx I draw textures like this:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture texture2;

@Override
public void create () {

    texture2 = new Texture("trojkat.png");
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(144, 96, 48, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();

    batch.draw(texture2,1,1);

    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

    texture2.dispose();
}
```

}

But in this tutorial it's built differently. I would like to draw everything in the main class, but do not know how to do it. To the above code had worked, in class MyActor I add a drawing function, it's now looks like this:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor
```

{

```
private Actor actor;
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("trojkat.png"));
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha)
{
    batch.draw(texture,0,0);
}



public MyActor(Actor actor)
{
    this.actor = actor;
}



public Actor getActor()
{
    return actor;
}
```

}

Is it possible to draw everything in the main class when I using the stage?